# how to check read/write speed of storages android?

Tags: android

I want to check android internal/external storage read and write speed . i am unable to find any help . I came across some applications on play-store but i need to implement my own . any help is appreciable.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How about creating a timestamp before and a timestamp after reading and/or write operation. After that get the difference and using then divide the filesize by the mesured time.

Comment: thanks , but after dividing what will be my output ? i mean kb/s or mb/s?

Comment: @KK06 It depends on the size of your file.

Answer (score 1):

before reading use

```
long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
//do operation of read write
//after that check your time diffrenece
System.currentTimeMillis()-currentTime;//this is your execution time
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not trying to benchmark functionality in your own application since you've been looking in the play store for solutions. If you are though, you can ignore everything until my last point. That still stands.

---

Examining read and write speed has a few complications which makes it hard to do.

Firstly, memory performs different depending on the size of data you throw at it. Smaller files might operate faster than larger ones for example.

Secondly, writing your own solution for this means writing and reading large amounts of random data. Memory wears down after a lot of writes though I'm not sure what the stretch is on those modules.

Also keep in mind the phone needs to be running in order to test the performance of the memory. There will be processes running alongside your test which also affect the performance of the memory (IO by other applications).

Lastly, what are you actually trying to achieve? We'd be more capable to help if we'd know your intentions as there might be alternative ways to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for comment sir.. no its not any benchmark functionality. Its all about device info i need to fetch . in which there is need of read/write speed functionality.

Comment: No problem, I wish I could give a more elaborated answer but I simply do not have the knowledge required to say anything more in depth about memory benchmarking. You might find some good information via Google on how to perform such tests. I'd say it's near impossible to compute near-truthful statistics though.